# Python Scoping - What is the best practice for passing in variables / dictionaries / sets into inner functions?

Tags: python, scope, parameter-passing, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I was solving a leetcode problem which entailed the usage of BFS/DFS graph traversal.

I left out much of the code that is irrelevant to this question, so ignore the actual function of following snippet which doesn't compile as is anyway:

```
class Solution:
    def foo(self):
        adj = defaultdict(list)
        visited = set()
        
        def dfs(key):
            for v in adj[key]:
                if v not in visited:
                    visited.add(v)
                    dfs(v)
            return 
        
        for i in bar:
            if i not in visited:
                dfs(i)
        
        return
```

What I am wondering about is the best practice for handling the `visited` set. It is declared within the `foo()` function, but I reference it within `dfs()` which is a function declared within `foo()`. Now the code works since I am calling the `.add()` method for the set, which in my understanding, makes Python look out for the `visited` variable in the 'next-outer' function scope of `foo()`, as there is no local declaration for `visited` within `dfs()`. (correct me if I am wrong)

Now, this is from what I understand kind of a special case, as it wouldn't work if I had written e.g.:
`visited += [v]` instead of using .add().

Same goes for immutable types as int e.g., therefore I wouldn't be able to modify an int variable declared in the `foo()` scope from within `dfs()` without passing it in.

My question is, what is the best code practice here, in terms of passing in variables into inner functions. Should I pass in the `visited` set into `dfs()` as well for consistency / readability? How would you deal with this in the context of a coding interview?